# MongoDB $in operator consider as Equality or as Range?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

when building an index in mongoDB using the [ESR rule](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-indexing)
will the operator `$in` considered as **E**quality  type or as **R**ange type ?

Comment: You can find out by trying the `explain` on your query.

Comment: i don't think so , how ... exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i am not able to answer more clearly than the documentation says, that `$in` acts like range, when used with `.sort()`

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/equality-sort-range-rule/#additional-considerations